# Is it possible to make this pattern more DRY?

Tags: exception, language-agnostic, control-flow

I've run into this a few times:

```
try {
  if (condition()) {
    return simpleFunction(with, some, args);
  } else {
    return complexFunction(with, other, args);
  }
catch (something) {
  // Exception thrown from condition()
  return complexFunction(with, other, args);
}
```

Is there any way (in any language) to avoid repeating the call to complexFunction? Ideally without obscuring the intent of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if c#, you could do...

```
    try
    {
        if (condition()) {
            return simpleFunction(with, some, args);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Swallow and move on to complex function
    }

    return complexFunction(with, other, args);
```

**Updated to have condition exception continue up the stack**

```
if (condition()) {
    try
    {
        return simpleFunction(with, some, args);
    }
    catch
    {
        // Swallow and move on to complex function
    }
}
return complexFunction(with, other, args);
```

Comment: This doesn't catch exceptions thrown from condition though, only from simpleFunction()

Comment: Indeed, I assumed you were catching simplefunction(). I'll update

Comment: Thats pretty good! I know I didn't mention it in the question, and I haven't run into it in practise either, but can you update it so that it can handle a different kind of exception that is thrown from condition(), but this one should continue getting passed up the stack?

Comment: I habe updated as requested.  `condition()` will now get caught and sent up the stack as requested

Comment: Hold up... that's how i had it originally...? (as pointed out in comment 1. Sorry I might be misunderstanding

Comment: Sorry, I was tired and thought it would require setting an exception type _not_ to catch. My bad.

Comment: No worries, I know the feeling

Answer (score 0):

Throw the exception if `condition()` fails

```
try
{
  if (condition())
  {
    return simpleFunction();
  }
  throw conditionException();
}
catch(conditionException ce)
{
  return complexFunction();
}
```

As has been so kindly pointed out, this is not the way code should be written.  It does, however solve the question - and to some extent it does seem to match the intent of the 'pattern' in the question, namely that if the condition throws an exception or returns false it's considered to have failed.

Comment: Cool! I didn't think of that one.